# Java constructor cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, android

After having gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074568/constructor-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types) question I'm still unable to build the following file:

```
public class ContextImpl implements Context {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContextImpl.class);

private static final Map<String, TransportFactory> transportFactories = new HashMap<>();
private static final Map<String, SerializerFactory> serializerFactories = new HashMap<>();

ContextImpl() { }

ContextImpl(boolean isSecureContext) {
    registerSerializerFactory(new CDRSerializerFactory());
    if(isSecureContext) {
            registerTransportFactory(new TcpBlockTransportFactory(/*secure = */true));
            registerTransportFactory(new HttpTransportFactory(/*secure = */true));
    } else {
            registerTransportFactory(new TcpBlockTransportFactory(/*secure = */false));
            registerTransportFactory(new HttpTransportFactory(/*secure = */false));
    }
}

private static SerializerFactory getSerializerFactoryByName(String serializerName) {
    synchronized (serializerFactories) {
        return serializerFactories.get(serializerName);
    }
}

private static TransportFactory getTransportFactoryByName(String transportName) {
    synchronized (transportFactories) {
        return transportFactories.get(transportName);
    }
}

public static TransportFactory getTransportFactoryByURI(String uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    return getTransportFactoryByURI(new URI(uri));
}
}
```

where the constructor of the above class is invoked as:

```
public static Context createContext() {
        return new ContextImpl();
    }
```

and the methods being called inside the constructor are:

```
private static void registerTransportFactory(TransportFactory transportFactory) {
        if (transportFactory == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("transportFactory");
        }
        final String transportName = transportFactory.getName();
        if (transportName == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("transportName");
        }
        synchronized (transportFactories) {
            transportFactories.put(transportName, transportFactory);
        }
    }

    public static void registerSerializerFactory(String serializerName, SerializerFactory serializerFactory) {
        if (serializerName == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("serializerName");
        }
        if (serializerFactory == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("serializerFactory");
        }
        synchronized (serializerFactories) {
            serializerFactories.put(serializerName, serializerFactory);
        }
    }
```

The error message returned is:

```
Error:(29, 16) java: constructor ContextImpl in class org.fiware.kiara.impl.ContextImpl cannot be applied to given types;
  required: boolean
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Why is this error returned since the implicit constructor is called?

Comment: Looks a lot like you haven't recompiled `ContextImpl` since adding the zero-args constructor, so the code trying to use it is using an old class file.